# Knockout js valor por defecto en etiqueta select html

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Tengo una etiqueta de `select` en mi html con el enlace de Knockout js.

```
    <div id="divEditMunicipalitys" data-bind="visible: IsEdit">
<div class="form-horizontal" data-bind="with: MunicipalityModel">
    <h3><strong>Editar</strong></h3>
    <br />

    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="control-label col-md-2"><strong>Municipio:</strong></span>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="TextboxMunicipalityNameEdit" type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: MunicipalityName" maxlength="40" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <span class="control-label col-md-2"><strong>Provincia:</strong></span>

        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select id="ComboBoxProvincesEdit" class="form-control" data-bind=" value: ProvinceId, options: $parent.Provinces, optionsText: 'ProvinceName',
                    optionsValue: 'ProvinceId', optionsCaption: 'Seleccione una Provincia...',optionsDisableDefault: true"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <button class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: $parent.Update">Guardar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En lugar de que me aparezca `seleccione una provincia` quiero que si tengo un valor de una provincia que me salga seleccionada la provincia por defecto,

este es mi modelo que me llega con los datos requeridos y la provincia,

```
municipalityViewModel.Edit = function (model) {
    municipalityViewModel.IsNewButton(false);
    municipalityViewModel.IsBackToListButton(true);
    municipalityViewModel.ShowResult(false);
    municipalityViewModel.IsDetails(false);
    municipalityViewModel.IsNew(false);
    municipalityViewModel.IsEdit(true);
    municipalityViewModel.MunicipalityModel().MunicipalityId(model.MunicipalityId);
    municipalityViewModel.MunicipalityModel().MunicipalityName(model.MunicipalityName);
    municipalityViewModel.MunicipalityModel().ProvinceId(model.ProvinceId);
    municipalityViewModel.MunicipalityModel().ProvinceName(model.ProvinceName);
    municipalityViewModel.MunicipalityModel().CreateBy(model.CreateBy);
    municipalityViewModel.MunicipalityModel().CreationDate(model.CreationDate);
    municipalityViewModel.MunicipalityModel().ModifiedBy(model.ModifiedBy);
    municipalityViewModel.MunicipalityModel().ModifiedDate(model.ModifiedDate);
    LoadProvinces();
    LoadListMunicipalitys();
    //$('#ComboBoxProvincesEdit').val(model.ProvinceId);
    $('#TextboxMunicipalityNameEdit').focus();

};
```

no se si me entienden pero quiero que este formulario de editar como tengo un municipio con su provicia que me salga la provincia seleccionada por defecto en vez de `'Seleccione una Provincia...'`,

ayuda,

Comment: Vez que lo tengo comentado, fue porque lo intente y no me funciono

Comment: entiendo, mira de poner lo siguiente, `optionsDisableDefault: true`

Comment: @IvanIsayenko no me funciono.

Comment: @IvanIsayenko edite la pregunta

Comment: Tendrias que tener algo asi: 
`var vm = {
  AvailableValues: $parent.Provinces,
  Value: ko.observable($parent.Provinces[0])
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);`

luego en el select seria `<select data-bind="options: AvailableValues, value: Value"></select>`

Comment: @IvanIsayenko si pero no me va a seleccionar la provincia que me trae en el ProvinceId que es lo que quiero, porque la lista ya la traigo

Comment: entiendo. Si `ProvinceId` esta dentro de `$parent.Provinces` entonces  sustituye por lo siguiente `Value: ko.observable(ProvinceId)`

Comment: @IvanIsayenko no me funciono,

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89336/discussion-between-ivan-isayenko-and-ing-jose-valera).